# C# Random method

Tags: c#, windows, random, methods

I just developed 1 program, whats generates random numbers and letters and after just write result into XML file. But there is a problem like, if i press button to generate once, it doesn't do anything, if i press button second time in arrow it generates.

```
private static void ToXml(string xml_uri, string value)
{
    XDocument doc;
    if (File.Exists(xml_uri))
        doc = XDocument.Load(xml_uri);
    else
        doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"), new XElement("RndStr"));

    doc.Element("RndStr").Add(new XElement("Str", value));

    doc.Save(xml_uri);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string file_name = "file.xml";

    if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        ToXml(file_name, textBox1.Text);

    textBox1.Text = RndStr(10);
}
```

Comment: And the error is.. (Paste it to the original question in full)

Comment: Do you type anything in the textbox before clicking the button?

Comment: debugger is your friend...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        ToXml(file_name, textBox1.Text);

    textBox1.Text = RndStr(10);
```

With current information which you gave. I can say that on first clicking of the button the `textBox1.Text.Length = 0` because you are setting the text after executing the check about the length and also ToXml method. So put `textBox1.Text = RndStr(10);` over the if check and it should happen on first click.

On the second click the value of Text property is already set with the value of the first click and because of that everything is working on second click. Next time use debug it will help you a lot in the future. Search articles in the web about debugging.

Comment: If this is the correct answer (which I presume it is, since it was my first thought)... I'm starting to think people is just trolling stack overflow. Someone with the ability to create or load an Xml file checking if it exists first and add elements to it, would be able to catch this at first sight. Would be even easier to catch it than write the question in S.O... and questions like this are popping up more often than not. Is it me the only one thinking something is just not right?

Comment: Thank you ;)  its okey now. ;) I just didnt recognize that it should be happen before the if checks' ;)

Comment: @Jcl I suppose this is some kind of school assignment and parts of the code are given by the teacher or copy from notes in class. When I was in university the covering of debugging was so little, that I don't even bother to take a look into it at that time. Year after that I learn about it in depth when I wrote my own projects. Not every university/school have good education system. Also there are question in the meta about that a lot of questions can be resolve with easy debugging and a lot of users recognize it like you. I don't know what is the right approach, for now I try to help the guy.

Comment: @MaksimZaikin you are welcome, mark the answer as correct and good luck with your project.

Comment: probably its my own project its not from school part and i just thinked about it a lil bit and just get this problem.

Comment: @mybirthname I understand: not criticising you at all. Just very curious and somehow amazed at the OP (not at you). I'd find it a reasonable question with just the event code... but the `ToXml` function showed *some* reasonably more logic than "this is my first ever attempt at making a program", which is the only reason one would not catch this error at first glance, IMHO. No need to do any kind of debugging, just look and read the 3 lines of code and realize one is not in the correct flow position... for a "first time programmer", ok, for someone having coded that `ToXml` function, no-no